# How to build features for relation extraction for SVM?

Tags: nlp, nltk, information-extraction

The field of interest: Information Extraction

This is very new to me and I am trying to understand how to engineer features (whether lexical or semantic) in order to learn relationship in information extraction.

From papers, one of the simple steps to take features for supervised learning in relations between two named entities is

```
* The sequence of words between the two entities
* the part of speech tags of these words
* bag of words between the two words
```

Shouldn't the number of words between the two entities change depending on the training sentence you are looking at? Then, how to build feature vectors which are not consistent in their sizes?

For instance, see the following two sentences for learning person and organization with a relation: an owner of.

```
1. Mike is the owner of the company called, Spark.
2. Denis owns the black building called Halo.
```

For the example 1, the number of words between Mike and Spark are [is, the, owner, of, the, company, called] which are 7 feature words, while for the example 2, we have [owns, the, black, building, called] 5 feature words.

Where am I misunderstanding this problem? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you meant 'the bag of words between the two entities' in the 3rd point. The bag-of-words model creates vectors disregarding word order, and take into consideration the whole vocabulary of your corpus. The frequency of occurrence of each word is used as a feature for training a classifier.

Adapting to your example:

```
Sentence 1: "Mike is the owner of the company called, Spark."
Sentence 2: "Denis owns the black building called Halo"
```

From these two sentences, the vocabulary is as follows, assuming stop-words (i.e., the, is, of, etc.) are removed, and that you split the sentence into individual tokens:

```
vocabulary = {owner, company, called, owns, black, building}
```

You can then use the raw frequency of each word (note: you can also apply a more sophisticated measure like the TF-IDF):

```
Sentence 1: {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}
Sentence 2: {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

You can reduce the dimension of the vectors by applying lemmatization techniques, for instance reducing verbs to the root form. This can be done in Python NLTK:

```
>>> from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> lmtzr.lemmatize("owns","v")
u'own'
>>> lmtzr.lemmatize("owned","v")
u'own'
```

the 'v' indicates the part-of-speech (PoS) tag associated to each word, in this case a verb. You can also get the PoS-tags for a sentence with NTLK:

```
>>> s = "Denis owns the black building called Halo"
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
>>> print nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
>>> [('Denis', 'NNP'), ('owns', 'VBZ'), ('the', 'DT'), ('black', 'JJ'),('building', 'NN'), ('called', 'VBN'), ('Halo', 'NNP')]
```

Applying the stemming techniques your vocabulary would be:

```
vocabulary = {own, company, called, black, building}
```

I believe the sequence of words they refer in the paper is something similar, but you extract sequences of tokens, instead of simple tokens, this is also called n-grams.

Note that you can also set a feature (i.e., a dimension in your feature vector) which is a string containing the sequence of words or of PoS-tags between the two entities.

Can you point exactly the papers or papers you mentioned, that might help
further clarifying the answer.

Also, check:

[UTD: Classifying Semantic Relations by Combining Lexical and Semantic Resources](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/S10-1057)

which achieved the best results on the SemEval-2010  Task 8 on multi-way classification of semantic relations between nominals. They list 45 different features which can serve as inspiration for your work.

Comment: So, the size of the lexical word feature is then the size of the total vocabulary from given texts? That's where I was being confused, and if what I said is correct, then now things make sense. If this is true, then the feature vector size must be quite huge for very large documents since they would have more unique words in them.
[Ref1](http://ai.stanford.edu/~rion/papers/hypernym_nips05.pdf), [Ref2](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/I05-1033.pdf) are the two of several more references I'm reading.